# Django - Many to Many Model Returning None

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

Long time listener, first time poster. Hoping to get some help with my models issue.

I'm having trouble with my many to many relationship. When I submit a form, I want to have my user's info associated with the post that they create. I'm using a many to many because I will have an additional feature where other users can join in on that same trip.

Currently my data for my Trip tables creates fine, but my user isn't being linked to the Trip id so I can't render out their name on the template.

Below is my code. Appreciate any help!
Cheers

Here are my models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    objects = UserManager()

class Trip(models.Model):
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datefrom = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    dateend = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def travels(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['logged_user'])
    all_trips = Trip.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    user_trips = Trip.objects.filter(user=request.session['logged_user'])
    context = {
        "user_trips": user_trips,
        "all_trips": all_trips,
        "user": user,
    }
    return render(request, 'belt_exam/travels.html', context)

def addtrip(request):
    user_id = request.session['logged_user']
    createdtrip = Trip.objects.create(destination=request.POST['destination'], description=request.POST['description'], datefrom=request.POST['datefrom'], dateend=request.POST['dateend'])
    createdtrip.user.add(User.objects.get(id=user_id))    
    return redirect('/travels')
```

Here's my template:

```
{% for alltrip in all_trips.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{alltrip.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="travels/destination/{{alltrip.id}}">{{alltrip.destination}}</a></td>
        <td>{{alltrip.datefrom}}</td>
        <td>{{alltrip.dateend}}</td>
        <td>
        <form class="" action="travels/destination/{{alltrip.id}}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Join">
        </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4):

In the line

```
user_trips = Trip.objects.filter(user=request.session['logged_user'])
```

you are comparing the user id from the session with the `User` object. That will not work. Correct would be

```
user_trips = Trip.objects.filter(user=user)
```

But there is a better way to get the user trips. To every relation Django create a reverse relation. The name can be set as the `related` name attribute of the `ManyToManyField`

```
user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='trips')
```

Now you can just use that attribute on the target model as an object manager (like `objects`)

```
user_trips = user.trips.all()
```

Comment: Thanks Klaus! I'm still a little confused on how this works though. My "models.ManyToManyField(User)" sits on the Trip table. I'm trying to link the two tables together so I can add the user ID of the poster to the Trip ID.  Can you help explain further? Sorry I'm new to programming so thanks for your patience!

Comment: maybe this will help you to understand https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward